# Не активны кнопки во время выполнения программы winforms c++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

Программа состоит в следующем: имеется два pictureBox. По нажатию кнопки одновременно в оба окна выводятся два видео с камеры: первое обычное, второе с наложением матрицы ядер kernel(матрица накладывается по нажатии на radioButton),значения которых задаются через numericUpDown. Проблема собственно в том, что все вышеперечисленные кнопки не работают после того, как я запускаю камеру, я могу нажать на них только до этого. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Хрустальный шар показывает, что вам нужно вынести код, показывающий видео, в отдельный поток.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Хрустальный шар не подскажет, как это сделать?Я новичок в этих воросах